# Script to assign varying numbers to ascii characters

Tags: python, ascii

I'm attempting to print an ascii table based on the letter 'h'. For example, if I want h to equal 256, i would want to print out each of the other 128 characters based on h's value. If I wanted h to equal 1005, again, I'd need to print all of the remaining ASCII characters based on h's placement. I feel like the code I have below is on the right track with the action 'index + n' but I'm not too sure:

```
import string

values = dict()

for index, letter in enumerate(string.printable):
        values[letter] = index + 'some number'

print values
```

Comment: string.printable isn't in ascii order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so first you have to generate an ASCII table in Python. `string` cannot do that, however you know the indexes are from 0 to 127 included, and the `chr` function outputs a given character for an index.

You can now retrieve the index of `h` (or any other letter). You can deduce an offset, and apply this offset to the other letters. Here is the code to compute everything:

```
h_desired_index = 1200

ascii_table = list(map(chr, range(128)))
h_index = ascii_table.index('h')
delta_index = h_desired_index - h_index
new_table = {}

for index, character in enumerate(ascii_table):
    new_table[character] = index + delta_index
```

The output I get:

```
{'\x00': 1096,
 '\x01': 1097,
 '\x02': 1098,
 '\x03': 1099,
 '\x04': 1100,
 '\x05': 1101,
 '\x06': 1102,
 '\x07': 1103,
 '\x08': 1104,
 '\t': 1105,
 '\n': 1106,
 '\x0b': 1107,
 '\x0c': 1108,
 '\r': 1109,
 '\x0e': 1110,
 '\x0f': 1111,
 '\x10': 1112,
 '\x11': 1113,
 '\x12': 1114,
 '\x13': 1115,
 '\x14': 1116,
 '\x15': 1117,
 '\x16': 1118,
 '\x17': 1119,
 '\x18': 1120,
 '\x19': 1121,
 '\x1a': 1122,
 '\x1b': 1123,
 '\x1c': 1124,
 '\x1d': 1125,
 '\x1e': 1126,
 '\x1f': 1127,
 ' ': 1128,
 '!': 1129,
 '"': 1130,
 '#': 1131,
 '$': 1132,
 '%': 1133,
 '&': 1134,
 "'": 1135,
 '(': 1136,
 ')': 1137,
 '*': 1138,
 '+': 1139,
 ',': 1140,
 '-': 1141,
 '.': 1142,
 '/': 1143,
 '0': 1144,
 '1': 1145,
 '2': 1146,
 '3': 1147,
 '4': 1148,
 '5': 1149,
 '6': 1150,
 '7': 1151,
 '8': 1152,
 '9': 1153,
 ':': 1154,
 ';': 1155,
 '<': 1156,
 '=': 1157,
 '>': 1158,
 '?': 1159,
 '@': 1160,
 'A': 1161,
 'B': 1162,
 'C': 1163,
 'D': 1164,
 'E': 1165,
 'F': 1166,
 'G': 1167,
 'H': 1168,
 'I': 1169,
 'J': 1170,
 'K': 1171,
 'L': 1172,
 'M': 1173,
 'N': 1174,
 'O': 1175,
 'P': 1176,
 'Q': 1177,
 'R': 1178,
 'S': 1179,
 'T': 1180,
 'U': 1181,
 'V': 1182,
 'W': 1183,
 'X': 1184,
 'Y': 1185,
 'Z': 1186,
 '[': 1187,
 '\\': 1188,
 ']': 1189,
 '^': 1190,
 '_': 1191,
 '`': 1192,
 'a': 1193,
 'b': 1194,
 'c': 1195,
 'd': 1196,
 'e': 1197,
 'f': 1198,
 'g': 1199,
 'h': 1200,
 'i': 1201,
 'j': 1202,
 'k': 1203,
 'l': 1204,
 'm': 1205,
 'n': 1206,
 'o': 1207,
 'p': 1208,
 'q': 1209,
 'r': 1210,
 's': 1211,
 't': 1212,
 'u': 1213,
 'v': 1214,
 'w': 1215,
 'x': 1216,
 'y': 1217,
 'z': 1218,
 '{': 1219,
 '|': 1220,
 '}': 1221,
 '~': 1222,
 '\x7f': 1223}
```

Comment: Thanks Flavian. This answered my questions perfectly!

Comment: Great! Don't hesitate to upvote and mark as answered! :)